# AWS Cloufront : Returns Access Denied using Signed Cookies

Tags: node.js, amazon-cloudfront

I'm able to access my origin objects using cloudfront signed url with custom domain.
The problem comes when i try to use cloudfront signed cookies , then i got a 403 Access Denied response from cloudfront.

```
<Error>
   <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
   <Message>Access denied</Message>
</Error>
```

I use exactly the same :

- bucket
- OAI credentials
- Key pair ID
- Private Key
- Policy

and my cloudfront and origin configuration that i use for signed url.

Below is the nodejs code that i use. I really don't know what's wrong.

Any help will be very appreciated!

Thank you!

```
var moment = require('moment');

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var keyPairId = 'APKAIPZ5BRDMEXAMPLE';

var privateKey = '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n' +
   'MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAsL+Tz/soZcDQLXcgJE89h5RHfZY+ddNIVI/3T0OvjOOFVRLp\n' +
   '0gN+06cwXWsvlmeEbnh5XdklA38H4p3wt5mxqip4YmuvbW6i+8UALHxPW0LTmiz0\n' +
   's4J6HB0eXhm3cbFV60i1DNat+W2q5miqlXqxKSdg+UbUGlFA5CbR\n' +
   '-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----';

var signer = new AWS.CloudFront.Signer(keyPairId, privateKey);
var expireTime = moment().add(3600, 'sec').unix();

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

   var domain = 'mydomain.com';
   var resource = 'https://cdn.mydomain.com/*';
   var attributes = '; domain=' + domain + '; path=/; secure; httpOnly'

   var options = {policy : '{"Statement":[{"Resource":"' + resource + 
   '","Condition":{"DateLessThan":{"AWS:EpochTime":' + expireTime + 
    '}}}]}'};

    signer.getSignedCookie(options, function(err, data) {

        if (err) {
        //do somehing

        } else {

           context.done(null, {

            'Set-Cookie': 'CloudFront-Policy=' + data["CloudFront-Policy"] + attributes,
            'SEt-Cookie': 'CloudFront-Signature=' + data["CloudFront-Signature"] + attributes,
            'SeT-Cookie': 'CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id=' + data["CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id"] + attributes


       });

    }
});
};
```

Comment: I have the very same problem. Did you manage to solve it in some way?

Comment: yes, use this script to calculate your expire time : 
`var expireTime = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000) + 3600;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using moment() use Math() function to calculate your expire time and it will does the trick!

```
var expireTime = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000) + 3600;
```